# Lazy loading routing not opening child module component

Tags: angular

I have an angular 6 Application in which I am using Lazy loading.

The lazy loading works well.

The problem I have is that I want to load different components within my child module based on the route.

Here is my App.Routes

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },        
    { path: 'login', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'manage/:id', loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule' },
    { path: 'organisation-list', loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule' }        
];
```

So for the url http:app.xxx.com/organisation-list it loads the Admin module with Routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'manage/:id', component: FlowListComponent },
{ path: 'organisation-list', component: PowerComponent },
{ path: '', component: FlowListComponent }
```

];

Now I was expecting the component PowerComponent to be loaded.  This does not happen and instead it loads the default FlowListComponent?

I've tried various things but I think my basic understanding on how this works is wrong.

Comment: `PowerComponent` would be loaded for `app.xxx.com/organisation-list/organisation-list`. The child paths are added to the parent paths.

Comment: @abetteroliver so how would I get the component to load with my base url? or would I always need to have app.xxx.com/module/component

Comment: @PNC Do you really only have two routes in AdminModule? If yes, then you can directly inject one of these child components directly to your template conditionally.

Comment: @abetteroliver no  have many - I just built it without lazy loading intially, so all the routes have no concept of 'module'.  If this is the only way, I'll need to change my urls to be 'admin/organisation-list' etc

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it like this
admin routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: PowerComponent },
  { path: 'manage/:id', component: FlowListComponent },
  { path: 'organisation-list', component: PowerComponent },
  { path: 'flow-list', component: FlowListComponent }
```

the one with path: '' is the default, I just checked it in a project I did a while ago.

Comment: I've gone for the approach of @abetteroliver where I have modified my urls to have app.xxx.com/admin/organisation-list.  This works - so I've just got to remap the urls to this scheme.

Answer (score 0):

as @abetteroliver suggested I needed to change my urls so now I have

```
export const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },        
{ path: 'login', component: HomeComponent },
{ path: 'manage/:id', loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule' },
{ path: 'admin', loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule' }
```

];

and...

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'manage/:id', component: FlowListComponent },
{ path: 'organisation-list', component: PowerComponent },
{ path: 'campaign-detail/:id', component: CampaignDetailComponent },]
```

when loading the organisation-list component I use the url

app.xxx.com/admin/organisation-list